# Using template folder from one app to another in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to use the template from my app to my server page. I created a page which have a button to change that page into pdf format.

[This is an image to find where my template page is in. And in the coding I tried to add html file in the line 28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q68Cb.png)

[This is the error which is showing when i select the "view pdf" url/button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgt1s.png)

[urls.py file and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omVrk.png)
[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUHVi.png)

```
class ViewPDF(View):
    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        pdf = render_to_pdf('templates/pdft.html')
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

In this coding how do i need to add the pdft.html template in the 3rd line?

[Error after changed the template path correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrrRJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is either:

1. The route is not configured properly OR
2. Django doesn't recognise the path inside render_to_pdf(). Try using `render_to_pdf('../api/templates/pdft.html')`

Comment: Still it is showing error. I have added urls.py file and the error

Comment: In your settings.py what is the template directory set to? Have you explicitly specified your path to templates? It should be something like 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../api/templates')]

Answer (score 0):

when you use `templates/pdft.html` then here is the HTML file that Django will try to load
`/path/to/your/project/api/templates/templates/pdft.html`.
 But your HTML file path is `/path/to/your/project/api/templates/pdft.html` so that's why using only `pdft.html` will work.

```
class ViewPDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pdf = render_to_pdf("pdft.html")
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type="application/pdf")
```

Comment: I have changed the path. Bit it's still showing as name error

Comment: can you also include TEMPLATES settings in your post.

Comment: I have included settings.py now.  I have written DIRS as os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') . Also I have tried the path you suggested too

Comment: @Deepika now you're getting a different error. I suggest you ask another question instead of changing the question every time different error comes.